# Separate structure for variables.tf gets "Object, known only after apply"

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have recently separated terraform files from it's variable file as per below structure

```
(root)
| main.tf
| users.tf
| roles.tf
├── Configuration (folder)
├──── azure-pipelines.yml
├──── .gitignore
├──── variables.tf
```

and since then I am getting bellow error messages

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 77, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "primary_account_storage_access_key":
│   77:   name         = "${module.variables.storage-account_name}-access-key"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.variables is a object, known only after apply
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "storage-account_name".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 78, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "primary_account_storage_access_key":
│   78:   value        = module.variables.storage-access_key
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.variables is a object, known only after apply
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "storage-access_key".
╵
```

This is how problematic resource `"primary_account_storage_access_key"` is defined

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "primary_account_storage_access_key" {
  depends_on   = [azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_sp_access]
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.azvault.id
  name         = "${module.variables.storage-account_name}-access-key"
  value        = module.variables.storage-access_key
}
```

Module is defined as below:

```
module "variables" {
  source = "./Configuration"
}
```

I have no issue with utilizing the same module in other resources placed in the same file (`main.tf`)

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = module.variables.storage-resource_group_name
    storage_account_name = module.variables.storage-storage_account_name
    container_name       = module.variables.storage-container_name
    key                  = module.variables.storage-key
  }
}
```

Found articles here on the site focusing on the error suggesting
"splat" operator with "toset" / "one" function, however that did not help:

```
  name         = "${toset(module.variables[*].storage-account_name)}-access-key"
  value        = toset(module.variables[*].storage-access_key)
```

```
  name         = "${one(module.variables[*].storage-account_name)}-access-key"
  value        = one(module.variables[*].storage-access_key)
```

Content of `variables.tf` what child module `variables` uses:

```
variable "storage-resource_group_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "Reporting-HFM-integration-rg"
}

variable "storage-account_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "reportinghfmintegration"
}

variable "storage-container_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "tfstate-blob"
}

variable "storage-key" {
  type    = string
  default = "terraform.tfstate"
}

variable "storage-access_key" {
  type    = string
  default = "u3K..."
}

variable "keyVault-name" {
  type    = string
  default = "se-dataplat-dwvault-prod"
}

variable "keyVault-resource_group_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "AzureDataPlatform-dwtools-prod-rg"
}

variable "keyVault-id" {
  type    = string
  default = "/subscriptions/23a89ca1-9743-4b3b-b5ff-41cea9985deb/resourceGroups/..."
}
```

Comment: What is the source code of your module?

Comment: @Marcin only source path is defined within the module, nothing else

Comment: But what is the source of the module? Actual files and code creating the module, especially its outputs.

Comment: @Marcin source is a local path grabbing content from `variables.tf`. I have added content of this file into my question (to the bottom), hope that it answers your question (new to modules)

Comment: The attributes of a reference like `module.example` are the output values declared in that module. So in order for `module.variables.storage-account_name` to be valid, there must be an `output "storage-account_name"` declared inside this `./Configuration` module.

Comment: @MartinAtkins you were right, It seems like I initially understood the concept of modules incorrectly, thanks for pointing this one out, solved my problem. Please feel free to make an answer out of your comment so that I can mark it as solution to my problem.